# How to add buttons in ContextMenu in Android

Tags: android

Hai All,

I am newbie to androids Apps, guys i have one doubt,Whether is it possible to add buttons(ok,cancel) in the ContextMenu,if so please provide some reference..

Forgive me if i have asked a silly novice question

Thanks a lot in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Buttons don't really belong in a menu. Perhaps what you really want is to use an onLongClick listener instead of onCreateContextMenu. Then you can pop up a dialog with buttons rather than a ContextMenu.